# How to show Popup in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, popup

I am new to MVC.How to Edit data in popup MVC3 razor.I goggled a lot but did not get it.
I am using jquery.
My controller-

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

        var q = from p in db.accs
                where p.id == id
                select p;
        return View(q.FirstOrDefault());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id,account ac)
    {
        acc a = (from p in db.accs
                     where p.id==id
                     select p).Single();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            a.f_name = ac.f_name;
            a.l_name = ac.l_name;
            a.Address = ac.Address;
            a.Phoneno = ac.Phoneno;
            db.SubmitChanges();
            int i = 2;
            return RedirectToAction("Display", new { i = i });
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Edit");
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to have a popup windows or popup div with a form inside? Do you want it to be ajax or normal POST?

Comment: i just want to edit details with validation but i don't know how?

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) component which allows you to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use Ajax.ActionLink which can return the partial view and then that result would be added to the div and then OnSuccess you show that partial view.

---

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("popup", "SomeAction", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "result",     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess="openPopup" })<br />

   <div id="result" style="display:none;"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#result").dialog({
             autoOpen: false,
               title: 'Title',
              width: 500,
             height: 'auto',
            modal: true
        });
   });
       function openPopup() {
         $("#result").dialog("open");
}
```